# WPF RibbonTab event needed

Tags: wpf, events, ribbon

I'm creating a little WPF-app. There, I implemented a ribbon-control `<ribbon:RibbonWindow...>`

It is working fine so far but I'd like to trigger an event, when the RibbonTab is clicked.
The only useful event I found is `IsVisibleChanged`, so I entered this:

```
<RibbonTab x:Name="StartTab" Header="Start" IsVisibleChanged="LoadProjectControl">
            <RibbonGroup Header="Projekt">
                <RibbonButton Label="importieren" LargeImageSource="Icons/import_48x48.png" Click="MnuImportEcad"/>
            </RibbonGroup>
        </RibbonTab>
```

The function:

```
private void LoadProjectControl()
{
    //Also tried with parameters (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)


    DataContext = new ProjectViewModel();
}
```

If I want to build the projekt, I get a "no overloading for LoadProjectControl CS0123"-error. I googled that but I have no idea how this works :(

Someone any idea?

Thanks Carsten

Comment: You certainly don't want to create a new view model each time the visibility changes. Consider using the Loaded event instead of IsVisibleChanged. Besides that, your event handler method has the wrong signature. It should be `private void LoadProjectControl(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)` or in case of the Loaded event, `private void LoadProjectControl(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event handler should accept an `object` and a `DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs`:

```
private void LoadProjectControl(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{

}
```